# Laravel 5.4 : send variable to controller and select it by class

Tags: php, laravel

Start from the begging I have this routes like this

`Route::resource( '/product-cat', 'ProductCategoryController' );`

and my Model

```
class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    use Translatable;
    public $translatedAttributes = ['name'];
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

and here is how I am sending the variable `$productCategory` to controller

```
<a href="{!! URL::route('product-cat.edit', $productCategory->id) !!}"> edit</a>
```

and this is the controller

```
public function edit( ProductCategory $productCategory ) {
        return view( 'product.category.edit', compact( 'productCategory' ) );
}
```

now in my controller I try to get the values of `$productCategory`
Trying `dd($productCategory)` but comes empty

other controller works fine. what I missing here.

Comment: rename $productCategory to $product-cat  and do a php artisan route:list and tell me the routes

Comment: @Leo instanceof Kelmendi Thanks for replay but I think I can't name var `$product-cat` do you mean `$product_cat` or `$productCat` OK here is the `route` `GET|HEAD  | supplier/product-cat/{product_cat}/edit | product-cat.edit         | App\Http\Controllers\ProductCategoryController@edit`

Comment: @YousefAltaf that seems to be the wrong route, you declared it on `/product-cat` but you shared `/product`

Comment: @apokryfos yes my bad edit it, by the way `$productCat` worked fine but can any one describe why it didn't work with `$productCategory` for my future knowledge

Comment: I think I got it if I not wrong it should be as the route `product-cat` so when I used `productCat` it worked fine thanks guys for help. Special thanks for  @LeoinstanceofKelmendi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for laravel route model binding to work, the name of type-hint model property in the method should match the route name.

So in your case the route looks like:

```
Route::resource( '/product-cat', 'ProductCategoryController' );
```

so that means to use route model binding type-hint var MUST be same name as `/product-cat` its a laravel rule.

So in your method :

```
public function edit( ProductCategory $productCat ) {
        return view( 'product.category.edit', compact( 'productCat' ) );
}
```